# Javascript Callback

Tags: javascript

I have the functions below:

*(Normally I get the variable msg by doing some query on a XML Object)*

```
function getMsg(callback) {
    var msg = "test"; 
    callback(msg);
}

function msgDone() {
    var message = null;

    getMsg(function(msg) {
       message = msg;
    });

    return message;  //Why is message undefined here?
}
```

My problem is that I get an undefined on message. I have tested the function `getMsg()`, and it returns the right value.

How will I make the msgDone to return the message that I get from callback? So that it doesn't return undefined?

Thanks

Comment: I dont see your problem, it is returning the right value

Comment: This might come in handy: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-to-return-the-response-from-an-ajax-call

Answer (score 0):

> Why is message undefined here?

It won't be, in the code in the question, but my guess is that the real `getMsg` is an *asynchronous* operation. That is, when you call it, it starts the process of getting the message but that process completes *later*, not right away. (For instance, a typical ajax call is like this.)

In that case, the reason `message` is undefined in the location you marked is that the callback hasn't been called yet, so nothing has ever assigned to `message`. You *can't* return the result of an asynchronous call from a function; instead, you have to provide a callback mechanism of your own (simple callbacks, or promises, or similar). E.g.:

```
function getMsg(callback) {
    // Do something asynchronous...
    // It's done, call the callback
    callback(/*...the data retrieved asynchronously...*/);
}

function msgDone(callback) {
    getMsg(function(msg) {
       // Presumably you do more processing here...
       // ...and then call the callback
       callback(msg);
    });
}
```

Then, instead of:

```
var msg = msgDone();
doSomethingWith(msg);
doSomethingElseWith(msg);
```

you do:

```
msgDone(function(msg) {
    doSomethingWith(msg);
    doSomethingElseWith(msg);
});
```